# Twitter Bootstrap - Multiple accordion buttons

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want two buttons to work for one accordion.
Both can toggle open/closed (collapsed).

Right now I can use both of the buttons to open and close the accordion, but only one button gets the `collapsed` added/removed.
How can I make both of the buttons add/remove the `collapsed` class when clicking on one of them.

Both of the buttons are like this, but in different locations:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-parent="#main3" href="#panel03">
```

I have not modified the accordion script and I couldn't find anything related to my problem in the Bootstrap documentation.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/46/

In the demo above I have two buttons. If you click one "active" gets added before it, both of the links need to have active once clicked. But only one gets active at the moment.

Comment: If you provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net with your relevant code it'll be easier to help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/46/ Only one button gets "active" added before it. I want both of them to have active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a work-around and doesn't really use the bootstrap toggling but it works.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/52VtD/47/)

```
$(".toggle-buttons a[data-toggle='collapse']").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest(".toggle-buttons").toggleClass("active");
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass($(this).data("toggle")).height("auto");
});
```

(Also changed the DOM a bit)

Answer (score 0):

Italy's answer did work but it didn't seem to be compatible with Bootstrap 3 so I remade it.

```
$("a.accordion-toggle[data-toggle='collapse']").on("click", function () {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").toggleClass("collapsed");
});
```

It's shorter and easier to understand I hope.